# JDBC Prepared Statement Confused about session scope

Tags: java, sql, t-sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am running into an issue when upgrading my JDBC driver. I have tried two different drivers
JNetDirects JSQLConnect and Microsofts driver both are displaying the same behavior. When executing multiple prepared statements in a nonauto-committing state the statements do not seem to be sharing session state. This is causing me trouble. Is there any way to instruct the connection that the statements should share the same session state?

Here is an example of how to replicate not sharing session state. The following fragment throws an exception on line `insert.execute();`. The exception caused by identity insert being off demonstrating that the session state was not maintained between the two prepared statements.

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement identityON = connection.prepareStatement("SET IDENTITY_INSERT TestStuff ON");
identityON.execute();
identityON.close();

PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TestStuff (id) VALUES(-1)");
insert.execute(); // Results in Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TestStuff' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. 
insert.close();

PreparedStatement identityOFF = connection.prepareStatement("SET IDENTITY_INSERT TestStuff OFF");
identityOFF.execute();
identityOFF.close();

connection.commit();

connection.close();
```

Table Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE TestStuff (
    id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,col int
)
```

In ruling out behaviors that may be at fault I made sure that session state is not cleared between batches

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TestStuff ON:
GO
INSERT INTO TestStuff (id) VALUES(-1);
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TestStuff OFF:
```

This will work when executed directly against an SQL Server instance. Demonstrating that batching doesn't effect the sessions scope.

Another curiosity is that @@IDENTITY will carry between the statements but SCOPE_IDENTITY() will not.

```
    PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TestStuff (Col) VALUES(1)");
    insert.execute();
    insert.close();

    PreparedStatement scoptIdentStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT @@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
    scoptIdentStatement.execute();
    ResultSet scoptIdentRS = scoptIdentStatement.getResultSet();
    scoptIdentRS.next();
    Short identity = scoptIdentRS.getShort(1);
    Short scopeIdent = scoptIdentRS.getShort(2);

    PreparedStatement maxIdStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(id) FROM TestStuff");
    maxIdStatement.execute();
    ResultSet maxIdRS = maxIdStatement.getResultSet();
    maxIdRS.next();
    Short actual = maxIdRS.getShort(1);

    System.out.println(String.format("Session: %s Scope: %s, Actual: %s", identity, scopeIdent, actual )); // Session: 121 Scope: 0, Actual: 121
```

Same example in SQL Server and result:

```
INSERT INTO TestStuff( col) VALUES (1)
PRINT CONCAT('Session: ', @@IDENTITY, ' Scope: ', SCOPE_IDENTITY() ) 
-- Session: 122 Scope: 122 (Can't print actual without polluting the output here)
```

Comment: *"causing me trouble"* Is that supposed to be a description of your problem? --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: @Andreas The code does not make it to the commit. It throws an exception on the insert. The code is a fragment that demonstrates the issue, not a complete program.

Comment: Sorry, then I added the wrong link. Here is the correct one: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ --- Don't paraphrase the exception. Show it, incl. stacktrace!

Comment: The second example illustrates the issue from a different point of view. Both are the same issue but demonstrated in different ways. @JavaDevil

Comment: You may want to consider using the generated keys retrieval support in JDBC instead of relying on `@@IDENTITY` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `PreparedStatement` to a `Statement` for `IDENTITY_INSERT` setting then this will work as you intend

```
Statement identityON = connection.createStatement();
identityON.execute("SET IDENTITY_INSERT TestStuff ON");
identityON.close();
```

Also note from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> SCOPE_IDENTITY: Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, if two statements are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.

and

> SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.

Hence the differing values from Management studio and from the JDBC driver.

Comment: That changes the problem domain. Statements cannot accept parameters making it a nonstarter. The middle statement must remain a prepared statement.

Comment: Yes and it can and it still works. As I mentioned it only needs to be the setting of `IDENTITY_INSERT` that needs to be a `Statement`